# for what need i max open file for service like mysql

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, service, ulimit

For what reason do I need *max_open_files* for a service like mysql?
I'm using one tomcat istance and only the tomcat service has access to my mysql databases.
For my tomcat istance 20 users have access to them. Does it means that the limit 1 for *max_open_files* for mysql is enough, because only the tomcat accesses mysql?

If some experts can give me 1 or 2 examples I would be happy.

Kind Regards
beardblack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If mysqld produces the error Too many open files, try increasing the
>   open_files_limit value.

You should read about the meaning of the parameter here: [open_files_limit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_open_files_limit)

In a nutshell, you can leave the default value and consider increasing it later. The number of concurrent users and application servers in a multi-threaded application could require higher values of the parameter.